# Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Localhelper_Helper_Basic' not found in /var/www/html/app/Mage.php on line 547

Tags: magento-1.9, module

Hello I have a problem with my custom module that I have created. 
I have backed up my magento through Admin panel then looked at the page later on and this has come up. I can see the header but can't see the content. I haven't done any changes to the files. A lot of people said it could be because of the compilations so I have disabled it and cleared cache, nothing happened.

This is my Basic class:

```
<?php
  class Bundle_LocalHelpers_Helper_Basic extends Mage_core_Helper_Abstract {}
```

And this is my config.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Bundle_LocalHelpers>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Bundle_LocalHelpers>
</modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <localhelper>
                <class>Bundle_LocalHelpers_Helper</class>
            </localhelper>
        </helpers>
    </global>
 </config>
```

It was working perfectly fine. I have also checked other questions but didn't find the right answer.

Comment: Is this all you have in your config.xml? Any routers? If not replace <localhelper> with <Bundle_LocalHelpers>

Answer (score 3):

You write it worked, so I assume the config.xml is loaded.

And I assume you call the helper via `Mage::helper('localhelper')`.

And I assume your helper lives in `app/code/community|local/Bundle/LocalHelpers/Helper/Data.php`

If this is all the case it is a hard nut to crack.

Start by making sure your etc/modules.xml is loaded, just break the XML and in dev mode you see a simple_xml error. If you see it, break the config.xml and make sure you see the same error.